# How to change IE 10 search engine in Windows RT

Tags: windows-8, search-engines, internet-explorer-10, windows-rt

With the Microsoft Surface right around the corner, I've been trying to live in Metro apps to see if I could live without the desktop in Windows 8. One thing I've noticed is that I can't change the default search engine in IE 10, or at least I can't change it without going to desktop. However, that option won't be available for Windows RT, because there is no desktop mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the default search provider in IE10 Metro?](http://superuser.com/questions/495741/how-can-i-change-the-default-search-provider-in-ie10-metro)

Comment: @Luke: How can older threads be marked as dupes of newer ones?

Comment: @karan Because I marked the wrong one... a good reason why it needs more votes to actually close. Sorry Caleb

Comment: @Luke don't worry about it!

Comment: The Desktop mode does exist in Windows RT, because it's needed for the included version of Office, running the various management tools hosted of MMC and control panel, and running Desktop IE for times when ModernUI IE doesn't cut it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desktop mode is available in Windows RT, and includes the desktop edition of IE 10.

To change the ModernUI/Metro IE search provider do the following:

1. Launch the desktop.
2. Open IE on the desktop.
3. Select the down arrow on the address bar, and select "Add" (Add search providers).
4. Locate the search provider you want, and Add to IE, not forgetting to "Set as default".

   - If you do forget to set it as default, click on the settings cog, and select "Manage add-ons", select "Search Providers", select your preferred search engine, and press "Set as default".
5. Open the ModernUI version of IE - if it's already running, I recommend closing it down - and try searching from the address bar - you are now using your preferred search engine.

I've just been through these steps on my surface, and it's working a treat.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I had no idea this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

With the current RTM version of Windows 8, Bing is baked into the RT version of IE10, and thus cannot be changed. Last I checked this is a common feature request on the MSDN forums so it may be changed later on in an update/service pack.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my Surface, changed through the desktop instance of IE that comes with Windows RT.

Comment: Good, then that means they fixed it in the release. That method did not work for me when I answered this question.