# How can I change the default search provider in IE10 Metro?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, windows-rt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change IE 10 search engine in Windows RT](https://superuser.com/questions/485100/how-to-change-ie-10-search-engine-in-windows-rt)

Is there a way to change the default search provider for IE10 Metro?

Comment: Is indeed a duplicate; didn't catch the other topic in search. Thanks much!

Comment: No problem! Duplicates actually help other questions get more views and show up in more search results.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: it is possible now. See the question this marked a duplicate of.

Is cannot be changed, quite controversially! Maybe they'll allow that in the future, but for now it's Bing.

**Edit:** I see you know this now.